# PL-SQL Lastest record within a group: looking for alternate (PARTITION BY?) approaches

Tags: plsql

Using PL-SQL, I need to find the record with the lastest INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT value within a group of records that share the same value for SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY and RPT_PER_KEY.

How else might this be done? Are there analytical functions for this type of query?

```
  SELECT
    m1.*
FROM
    HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT m1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT m2
            ON (
                m1.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY = m2.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY
                AND m1.RPT_PER_KEY = m2.RPT_PER_KEY
                AND m1.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT < m2.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT)
WHERE
    m2.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY IS NULL
ORDER BY
    m1.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY
   ,m1.RPT_PER_KEY
   ,m1.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_CD
   ,m1.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT
```

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I didn't say anything about a stored procedure. I'm just looking for a PL-SQL query.

Comment: PL/SQL **is** (only) for stored procedures. So if you say "using PL/SQL" you are saying "using a stored procedure".

Comment: Ah. I thought that it just referred to Oracle's implementation of SQL. thx.

Comment: Darn My query is wrong anyways.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.*
FROM
    HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY
           ,HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.RPT_PER_KEY

           ,MAX(HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT) AS MAX_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT
        FROM
            HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2
        GROUP BY
            HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY
           ,HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.RPT_PER_KEY
    ) HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2

        ON
            HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY = HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY
            AND HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.RPT_PER_KEY
            = HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.RPT_PER_KEY

            AND HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT = HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT2.MAX_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT

ORDER BY
    HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.SHPMNT_LN_ITEM_KEY
   ,HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.RPT_PER_KEY
   ,HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_CD
   ,HD_INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT1.INVC_LN_ITEM_STAT_START_DT;
```

It's longer but arguably more intuitive. I would like other people's opinions on which is more efficient.